# cv2.FindHomography()crashes in Jupyter

Tags: python, opencv

As the title explains, I am trying to find the homography between two views by the matches obtained from BFMatcher() for my SuperPoint implementation. When I runfindHomography over 30 matches, Jupyter crashes but if I do for 20 matches it runs. I wonder why this is the case. Here are the versions of libraries I am on:

```
`Python = 3.8.10
Docker = nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:23.10-py3
opencv = 4.7.0
opencv-python = 4.8.1.78
opencv-python-headless = 4.8.1.78`
```

Thank you!

Installed different versions of opencv, did not work
Removed opencv-python-headless, raised issue of missing 'BFMatcher' and '_ _ version _ _' attributes (added spaces to prevent formatting here).

Comment: So far what you describe sounds like a symptom of memory being exceeded. And so your title would be more specifically 'cv2.FindHomography()crashes in Jupyter when I try a lot of matches' because **the title 'cv2.FindHomography()crashes in Jupyter' is not accurate** as it works for 20 and does not crash. (See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about writing a title.) Did you try any matches over 20 or any other under 300? Did you try running this as pure Python in a script with headless, separate from Jupyter, to see if you could get further with ...

Comment: <continued> more matches? Try it on a system with more resources?

Comment: Sorry If was not clear in framing the question. Anything above 30 ends up in kernel crashing. For the latter, I am not sure how to run a pure python script with headless, as I do import cv2.

Comment: "When I runfindHomography over 300 matches, Jupyter crashes but if I do for 20 matches it runs." Oh. You have a big typo there because you wrote `300` in your original post. You should edit that to `30`.  It still sounds like a memory issue and not specific to anything beyond you overtaxing your system. You mentioned headless so I thought you knew it. Sometimes the overhead of Jupyter makes Python crash earlier than if you ran it as a traditional Python script.

Comment: why do you have multiple package variants of opencv installed? and where did you get an `opencv` package from? that's not one of the official packages.

Comment: @Wayne this is the output when I run as pure Python Script.

`INTEL MKL ERROR: //usr/local/lib/libmkl_def.so.1: undefined symbol: mkl_sparse_optimize_bsr_trsm_i8.
Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load libmkl_def.so.1.`

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz The docker image from nvidia has opencv installed by default. I am trying to update the native opencv but I am unable to do so. opencv-python and headless are installed via pip. removing opencv makes the container unusable.

Comment: Looks like running it as Python won't help then. This comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36659453/intel-mkl-fatal-error-cannot-load-libmkl-avx2-so-or-libmkl-def-so#comment124404106_36659453) says that was seen when not requesting enough memory. Which again is consistent with you overtaxing your system. So where you are working you are limited to 20. You'd need a better system to run more than 20. So .... your title is still inaccurate.

Comment: 20 matches is a ridiculously small number. that can't possibly tax any reasonable system's RAM. you'd have to be running on something that is so starved for RAM, it couldn't even hold an entire image in RAM. why have we not been shown any code or anything approaching the requirements of a [mre]?

Comment: @Wayne, the configuration is as follows:
CPU: Ryzen 5995wx (64C/128T)
GPU: 2x RTX 6000 Ada (48G VRAM)
RAM: 1TB

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, since this is a work related question I'm not sure I am allowed to show code here. But this  implementation is close to https://github.com/shaofengzeng/SuperPoint-Pytorch repo.

Comment: Thanks, Christoph for adding some vastly more informed domain knowledge. I was just looking at it seeming to fit the characteristics of a memory issue. @ShreyasRamesh , if you read what Christoph referenced you'll see toy data or a toy implementation would go a long way. On top of that then allowing others here to help you, part of that is to help you troubleshoot things on your own, too; often in trying to develop a toy or generalized example, you can find what is going on or the differences that contribute. So now you reference an implementation that is close, does it crash ...

Comment: <continued> when you do more than 20? If not, can you make it more like yours in some way and then does it crash when you try more than 20? And if so, describe to us or share the situation through a repo or gist if if it needs more stuff to share. For example, you can fork the implementation you say is close and make it behave like you see and then provide a link that here. Follow the advice in the name of section on [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) where the minimal reproducible example comes up,  'Help others reproduce the problem'.